# Nodejs promise queue vs cluster mode

Tags: node.js, promise

I have a Node.js script which gets tasks from the server and performs some operations on data.
Inside it runs a while(true) loop in which it gets a task from the server, waits for its completion and pushes the result back to the server.

I would like to scale it, so many tasks could be performed concurrently.
So I discovered two choices:

> 1. Use a [promise queue](https://github.com/sindresorhus/p-queue). E.g. Get task, put to queue
> 2. Just process one task on time, but run many instances of the script (in cluster mode?)

I wonder which is better and if use second option will it consume more RAM than the first one?

Comment: Having a `while(true)` loop in a nodejs implementation really strikes me .. Did you use a library to handle your requests ?

Comment: Yes, it’s just a http request so i use `axios`. I consider changing `while(true)` for something else, probably ‘EventEmitter`

Comment: Oh, okay, it's a client, I thought you were implementing a server. Okay, but `setInterval()` seems more appropriate for that matter

Comment: If you'll run a few instances of your script how do you will manage what instance should process request from the server? You need to know what instance is _idle_, and send request to this instance. I think run one instance makes more sense.

Comment: I think that’s not the case because client gets task from server on request so if it’s idle it just requests task

Comment: It entirely depends on the sort of tasks that need to be handled. Generally speaking though, you'd use a dedicated task queue or messaging platform and have X amount of worker processes reading tasks from the queue and processing them. Also generally speaking, a promise queue would only make sense if the tasks are mostly I/O-bound (as opposed to CPU-bound).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I used RabbitMQ as messaging queue. It's client library `amqplib` eliminates usage of `while(true)` loop and you can scale it greatly by spawning more proccesses. It can also process multiple tasks at the same time by setting `prefetch count` to a value greater than 1.